# Find a function comparing two variables that is equal to 1 when they are equal and 0 when they are not

Tags: inequality, binary, integers

I am trying to find a function that compares two variables. When these two variables are equal, the function should equal 1. For any other value, the function should equal 0. Is there a way to do this without using logic arguments?

My naive attempt to do this uses floor and ceiling notation (possibly incorrectly) where I end up using logic to get my result. Here is my best attempt:

min[max[1+x-y,0],max[1+y-x,0]]

[Hand Drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnEUe.png)

Is there a way to write this as a function without the floor/ceiling max/min logic?

Comment: @GerryMyerson in reference to http://mathoverflow.net/users/84515/mike-l

Comment: [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

Comment: I got this answer from MO stack and thought it would be worth sharing:    1−sgn(x−y)2  @MaxAlekseyev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}1&x=y\\
0&x\neq y
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks for the response! Is there a way to arrange this algebra more expressly so that I don't have to use floor/ceiling functions?

Comment: There are no floor or ceiling functions in this expression.

Comment: Said another way (I am naive) how do I implement this into something like MATLAB or Excel without using min/max functions?

Comment: @MikeL: it sounds like you are trying to describe a discontinuous function using continuous formulas.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I was going to say that but held back at the risk of being wrong and adding confusion. Is there a more elegant way to analyze a data set with a discontinuous function like this or am I trying to over simplify?

Comment: You seem to find something wrong with $f$ expressed as cheesyfluff did, when that's the direct and natural way. What value would a convoluted formula give you over that?

Comment: =IF(A1=A2, 1, 0) is the function you want in excel, where A1 and A2 can be any cell. The general syntax for an if statement in excel is =IF (Logic_Test, Value_if_True, Value_if_False).

Comment: @cheesyfluff: That makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: @MartinArgerami: I thought I was making the problem more clunky and that I might have been missing something. I appreciate the education from both of you!

Comment: @cheesyfluff Most programming languages allow you to use the value of a Boolean expression as an integer without having to resort to a clumsy (and redundant) conditional. In Excel, you can coerce the value to an integer, either explicitly with INT or implicitly by doing arithmetic on it. The latter is why “--(_expr_)” is a common idiom for this conversion in Excel. Either way, the value will be $0$ or $1$. In MATLAB, the value of a logical expression is already $0$ or $1$, so there’s nothing more to do. Wolfram Language supports Iverson brackets, and so on.